# MPDF error when generating to PDF

Tags: mpdf, fuelphp

I'm having issues generating HTML/PHP code to PDF. Im using mPdf
Here is my code:

```
<table id="packing_slip">

<?php

foreach($sheets as $s):
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    $name= explode(' ',$s['customer_name'])
    ?>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    </div>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Hi <?php echo $name[0] ?>!</h2>
    <div align="center">
        <br> Here is your delivery for: <br>
        <?php echo date('l, F dS', strtotime($s['delivery_week']));?>
        <br>
        ORDER NO. <?php echo $s['order_id'] ?>&nbsp; | &nbsp;  CUSTOMER NO.<?php echo $s['client_id'] ?>
        <?php $query="select * from orders left join deliveries on orders.id = deliveries.order_id left join deliveries_meals on deliveries.id = deliveries_meals.delivery_id where orders.id = '{$s['order_id']}'";
        $result_main = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $row_main = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_main);

        $query_meals = "select label, subtitle, meals.name from meal_options left join meals on meal_options.meal_id = meals.id where meal_options.id ='{$row_main['meal_option_id']}' ";
        $result_meals = mysqli_query($conn,$query_meals);
        $row_meals = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_meals);

        ?>
        <hr style="height: 5px;border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-bottom:0px">
        <hr style="height: 5px;border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;">
    </div>
    <?php foreach($s['meals'] as $m):?>
    <h3><?php echo $row_meals['name'];?> </h3>
    <h5><i><?php
            if($row_meals['label'] != '' && $row_meals['subtitle'] != ''){ echo $row_meals['subtitle'] . " & " . $row_meals['label'];}
            elseif ($row_meals['label'] != '' ) {echo "with " . $row_meals['label'];}
            else{ echo $row_meals['subtitle'];}?></i> </h5>
    <?php echo $m['count']?> &nbsp; SERVING SHIPPED<br><br>
    COMPONENTS
    <hr align = "left" style="width: 115px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px">
    <br>
    <?php if (@$m['components'][0] != ''){?>
        <?php foreach($m['components'] as $c):?>
            <?php echo $c?><br>
        <?php endforeach;
    } else {echo "Everything is included in package. <br>";}
    ?>
    <br>
    <?php if($m['instructions'][0] != '' || $m['instructions'][1] !=''){?>
        INSTRUCTIONS
        <hr align = "left" style="width: 115px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px">
        <br>
        <?php if($m['instructions'][0] != ''){echo "Microwave : ".$m['instructions'][0];}?><br><br>
        <?php if($m['instructions'][1] != ''){ echo "Stovetop : ".$m['instructions'][1];}?><br>
    <?php }?>
    <hr align="left" style="width: 400px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
<?php endforeach;?>
    <hr align="left" style="width: 600px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
    <div align="center"><h3> Thank you,<?php echo $name[0] ?>!</h3>
        <hr style="width: 600px; border-top:1px solid #000 !important;margin-top: 5px !important;margin-bottom:0px" >
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

<?php

include('mpdf60/mpdf.php');

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$mpdf->debug = true;

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p style="color:red;">Hello World<br/>Fisrt sentencee</p>');

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

I put for now "Hello World" but I actually want to put my whole code, also I get this error:
`Output has already been sent from the script - PDF file generation aborted.`
How can I fix this? I am using FuelPhp, Im not sure how I can add it to the PDF, any ideas on how it can work. Because right now it is not even letting me put "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

You are now trying to do two mutually exclusive things: display HTML code in the browser **and** display a PDF document in the browser.

Displaying the PDF (calling the `Output` method without parameters) tries to set correct HTTP `Content-type` headers, but cannot do so as there already is an output - as the error message states.

Be sure that you disable all layouting your framework provides as it produces the exact same output that could cause this.

You can solve your problem either by surrounding your HTML code with `ob_` handlers and using caught output

```
<?php

ob_start();

?> ... HTML code ... <?php

$html = ob_get_clean();

...

$mpdf->writeHtml($html);
```

or by generating your HTML code into a PHP string entirely:

```
<?php

$html = '<table id="packing_slip">';

foreach($sheets as $s):
$html .= "<tr>";
$html .= "<td>";
```

See also https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/error-messages.html

Comment: I tried the first option with the `ob_start();` however a pdf downloads but when I open it I get "Failed to load PDF document." do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Also does `ob_start(); ` have to be at the very beginning of the page?

Comment: If you are sending the PDF to download or inline to display in the browser, you must not print anything yourself, not even *after* calling the `Output` method. So yes, ob_start should be at the beginning of your code, and there must not be any output (print/echo/etc) after calling the `Output` method.

Comment: You might want to lose the `?>` PHP closing tag as any whitespace after it is also considered an output and will possibly corrupt the  PDF file.

Comment: Can you see my other questions I still get the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690267/failed-to-download-pdf-file-using-mpdf